# Azure tfs-cli is not including all files (.vsix)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing extension for azure devops and have some project. 
The problem is that after publishing, while opening extension on azure devops it can't find some files and returns 404.

So it sends GET request to for example:

```
https://myID.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/myID/extension-name/1.0.0/1369826713111/assets/folder/file.png
```

Response:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccountNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified account does not exist. RequestId:bbdd4d8b-310e-002a-315c-62case000000 
Time:2019 09-30T06:59:31.4731552Z</Message>
</Error>
```

But If I regenerate .vsix file again using

> tfx extension create

via tfs-cli it could include the file which wasn't included before, but now it is missing another one, for example file_2.png and so on.. And actually there is missing max 1-3 files.

It was working good, and after smth gone wrong.. Btw I'm sure 99% that it's something wrong on their (azure) side. Because I'm using version control and now, even on old version, it's not working.

May be is anyone having the same problem and it's smth wrong on my side?

Thank you !

Comment: Of course, problem can be on azure gallery cdn server, where from we are trying to get files. Btw I think actually the problem is on the gallery server, because tfs-cli repository was updated ~ month ago

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was on azure side. Fortunately, it's solved.